# Mac OS X kernel panic after TM restore

Tags: macos, time-machine, restore, kernel-panic

I changed my HD in my MacBook Pro, and restored from Time Machine backup.  Now I keep getting kernel panic error everytime I restart.

I booted from the DVD and ran a few tests, noticed that HD and RAM are being detected, also did a repair on the disk through disk utility, still getting same error.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a basic install without a restore, and see if that runs.  That will eliminate hardware problems.  Then try restoring the Time Machine backup.

Comment: this is what i did, before seeing this answer, and it worked.  but since it was what helped in my case, it's the answer to my question!

Answer (score 1):

Post the Kernel Panic log file.  It *might* point to a culprit.

Answer (score 0):

I would try running [DiskWarrior](http://www.alsoft.com/Diskwarrior/index.html), which is more thorough than Disk Utility. Wade's suggestion to look at the logs is also good.

Answer (score 0):

You may encounter the problem again.

There are a number of known reports of Time Machine causing periodic Kernel panics on some Macs.  My wife's MacBook Air had this issue, and the fix above got it running again, but they'd eventually re-occur during backups.   Becuase the panic doesn't occur on most backups, and the geniuses couldn't reproduce it, they advised her to disable time machine's auto-backups and run it manually every week or two.

Oddly, my machine backs up to the same time machine without incident, but hers continued to have it from time to time even after they replaced her entire motherboard and hard drive (for seemingly unrelated reasons).